# Network block after restart

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I'm running wheezy and I don't want to install network-manager.

I have a problem with network interfaces. When I restart the interfaces I cannot use any connection anymore.

I cannot reach internet or same subnet ip addresses.

here the `ifconfig`, `route`,`ping` and dns command before the restarting

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:59:af:51:17:c3
          inet addr:192.168.1.30  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9259:afff:fe51:17c3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:33873 errors:0 dropped:479 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4125488 (3.9 MiB)  TX bytes:113565 (110.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:56
```

`route -n`

```
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
 0.0.0.0         192.168.1.10    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
 192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

`ping google.com`

```
PING google.com (173.194.112.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra07s28-in-f4.1e100.net (173.194.112.36): icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=30.1 ms
64 bytes from fra07s28-in-f4.1e100.net (173.194.112.36): icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=29.8 ms
```

DNS

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After I run `service networking restart` or `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or stop and then start again the service I get `Destination Host Unreachable`.
I must reboot the system to get it work.

Any idea why this happens?

here the interfaces file content

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    gateway 192.168.1.10
    metric 0
```

Comment: Please append the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` to your question.

Comment: interfaces file content added

Comment: Hmm, `/etc/network/interfaces` seems to be OK (although the fields `network` and `metric` are probably superfluous). Can you post the output of `ifconfig`, `route -n` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` after you have executed `/etc/init.d/networking restart`?

Comment: after restarting the network I get exactly the same outputs

Comment: no one has the same problem?

Comment: There has to be something different in your configuration after you've restarted the network, or else it would still work. You'll need to find this difference so we can isolate the problem. Have you tried to ping an IP, for example `ping 8.8.8.8`? Maybe it's only the DNS resolution that breaks.

Comment: The dns configuration remains unvaried after restarting. I tried to `ping google.com` and `ping 192.168.1.65`(that is another linux pc) but I cannot reach anything. It seems that the network freezes. I'm actually using wheezy for BeagleBone Black, downloaded from [link](http://www.armhf.com/). Today I tested the new release, 7.0. Also with this new freshed disk image flashed into the SD card I got the freeze of the network after its restart. So, it seems to be something redundant in old and new releases... Any idea about that?

Comment: actually, I have another thing to say, when I ping a subnet ip address I get for answer `Destination Host Unreachable` but when I ping an outsider ip address I got nothing for answer.

Comment: Hmm... have you checked the `dmesg` output? Maybe the kernel module responsible for talking to your network card somehow locks up or breaks...

Comment: these rows are present in the `dmesg` log after I restart the network: _[  281.744386] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
[  281.752983] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1
[  281.758368] libphy: PHY 4a101000.mdio:01 not found
[  281.763418] net eth0: phy 4a101000.mdio:01 not found on slave 1
[  281.773447] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  283.757651] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
[  283.764302] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready_